# Cannot get traefik custom error pages in docker-compose to work

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I have been trying to use traefik with custom error pages configured in the docker-compose using labels, but I can't seem to get it working. I'm using nginx to serve the error page, and that works as a standalone host, but not as an 404:

```
 networks:
          - traefik
    labels:
          - traefik.backend=grex
          - traefik.port=3000
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:$DOMAIN
          - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https
          - traefik.frontend.errors.grex.backend=nginx
          - traefik.frontend.errors.grex.status=["400-599"]
          - traefik.frontend.errors.grex.query=/wait

nginx:
    image: nginx
    networks:
          - traefik
    labels:
          - traefik.backend=nginx
          - traefik.port=80
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/wait
```

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, this is my current configuration

```
    labels:
       - traefik.frontend.errors.grex.backend=nginx
       - traefik.frontend.errors.grex.status=400-599
       - traefik.frontend.errors.grex.query=/err.html

nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes: 
          - ./err.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/err.html
    networks: 
          - traefik
    labels:
          - traefik.backend=nginx
          - traefik.port=80
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/wait
          - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https
```